# Why is conda's remove not symmetric with conda's install?

Tags: anaconda, conda

Why do seemingly simple/atomic `conda` installs result in fairly complex uninstalls??

I recently tried the following `conda install`

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge imageio-ffmpeg 
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.7.12
  latest version: 4.8.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/smgutstein/anaconda2/envs/dnn_py3

  added / updated specs:
    - imageio-ffmpeg


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    imageio-ffmpeg-0.3.0       |             py_0          14 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:          14 KB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  imageio-ffmpeg     conda-forge/noarch::imageio-ffmpeg-0.3.0-py_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
imageio-ffmpeg-0.3.0 | 14 KB     | ################################################################################################################ | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

This seemed like a fairly atomic install.

However, when I tried to uninstall, things became *much* more complicated:

```
$ conda uninstall imageio-ffmpeg 
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.7.12
  latest version: 4.8.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/smgutstein/anaconda2/envs/dnn_py3

  removed specs:
    - imageio-ffmpeg


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    absl-py-0.8.1              |           py36_0         164 KB
    anaconda-client-1.7.2      |           py36_0         147 KB
    asn1crypto-1.3.0           |           py36_0         164 KB
    astor-0.8.0                |           py36_0          46 KB
    backcall-0.1.0             |           py36_0          20 KB
    backports-1.0              |             py_2         139 KB
    bleach-3.1.0               |           py36_0         221 KB
    c-ares-1.15.0              |    h7b6447c_1001          89 KB
    ca-certificates-2019.11.27 |                0         124 KB
    certifi-2019.11.28         |           py36_0         153 KB
    chardet-3.0.4              |        py36_1003         180 KB
    clyent-1.2.2               |           py36_1          19 KB
    cryptography-2.8           |   py36h1ba5d50_0         552 KB
    cudnn-7.6.5                |       cuda10.0_0       165.0 MB
    cycler-0.10.0              |           py36_0          13 KB
    cytoolz-0.10.1             |   py36h7b6447c_0         377 KB
    dask-core-2.9.1            |             py_0         556 KB
    defusedxml-0.6.0           |             py_0          23 KB
    entrypoints-0.3            |           py36_0          12 KB
    gast-0.3.2                 |             py_0          13 KB
    giflib-5.1.4               |       h14c3975_1          68 KB
    idna-2.8                   |           py36_0         112 KB
    imageio-2.6.1              |           py36_0         3.2 MB
    importlib_metadata-1.3.0   |           py36_0          46 KB
    ipykernel-5.1.3            |   py36h39e3cac_1         173 KB
    ipython-7.11.1             |   py36h39e3cac_0         988 KB
    ipython_genutils-0.2.0     |           py36_0          39 KB
    jasper-1.900.1             |       hd497a04_4         198 KB
    jedi-0.15.2                |           py36_0         738 KB
    joblib-0.14.1              |             py_0         201 KB
    jsonschema-3.2.0           |           py36_0          95 KB
    jupyter_client-5.3.4       |           py36_0         141 KB
    jupyter_console-6.0.0      |           py36_0          37 KB
    jupyter_core-4.6.1         |           py36_0          70 KB
    kiwisolver-1.1.0           |   py36he6710b0_0          82 KB
    lame-3.100                 |       h7b6447c_0         323 KB
    libiconv-1.15              |       h63c8f33_5         721 KB
    libprotobuf-3.11.2         |       hd408876_0         2.9 MB
    libsodium-1.0.16           |       h1bed415_0         214 KB
    libwebp-1.0.1              |       h8e7db2f_0         471 KB
    markupsafe-1.1.1           |   py36h7b6447c_0          29 KB
    matplotlib-3.1.1           |   py36h5429711_0         5.0 MB
    mistune-0.8.4              |   py36h7b6447c_0          55 KB
    more-itertools-8.0.2       |             py_0          39 KB
    nbconvert-5.6.1            |           py36_0         460 KB
    nbformat-4.4.0             |           py36_0         128 KB
    networkx-2.4               |             py_0         1.2 MB
    notebook-6.0.2             |           py36_0         4.0 MB
    numpy-1.17.4               |   py36hc1035e2_0           5 KB
    numpy-base-1.17.4          |   py36hde5b4d6_0         4.2 MB
    olefile-0.46               |           py36_0          48 KB
    openh264-1.8.0             |       hd408876_0         659 KB
    packaging-20.0             |             py_0          35 KB
    pandoc-2.2.3.2             |                0        14.0 MB
    pandocfilters-1.4.2        |           py36_1          13 KB
    parso-0.5.2                |             py_0          69 KB
    pexpect-4.7.0              |           py36_0          80 KB
    pickleshare-0.7.5          |           py36_0          13 KB
    pillow-7.0.0               |   py36hb39fc2d_0         600 KB
    pluggy-0.13.1              |           py36_0          33 KB
    prometheus_client-0.7.1    |             py_0          42 KB
    prompt_toolkit-2.0.10      |             py_0         227 KB
    protobuf-3.11.2            |   py36he6710b0_0         635 KB
    psutil-5.6.7               |   py36h7b6447c_0         318 KB
    ptyprocess-0.6.0           |           py36_0          23 KB
    py-1.8.1                   |             py_0          71 KB
    pygments-2.5.2             |             py_0         672 KB
    pyopenssl-19.1.0           |           py36_0          87 KB
    pyparsing-2.4.6            |             py_0          64 KB
    pyrsistent-0.15.6          |   py36h7b6447c_0          93 KB
    pysocks-1.7.1              |           py36_0          30 KB
    pytest-5.3.2               |           py36_0         365 KB
    pytest-runner-5.2          |             py_0          13 KB
    python-utils-2.3.0         |           py36_0          18 KB
    pywavelets-1.1.1           |   py36h7b6447c_0         3.5 MB
    pyyaml-5.2                 |   py36h7b6447c_0         180 KB
    pyzmq-18.1.0               |   py36he6710b0_0         453 KB
    qtconsole-4.6.0            |             py_1          97 KB
    requests-2.22.0            |           py36_1          92 KB
    scipy-1.3.2                |   py36h7c811a0_0        14.0 MB
    send2trash-1.5.0           |           py36_0          16 KB
    setuptools-44.0.0          |           py36_0         510 KB
    terminado-0.8.3            |           py36_0          26 KB
    toolz-0.10.0               |             py_0          50 KB
    tornado-6.0.3              |   py36h7b6447c_0         583 KB
    tqdm-4.41.1                |             py_0          54 KB
    traitlets-4.3.3            |           py36_0         140 KB
    urllib3-1.25.7             |           py36_0         169 KB
    wcwidth-0.1.7              |           py36_0          24 KB
    webencodings-0.5.1         |           py36_1          19 KB
    werkzeug-0.16.0            |             py_0         255 KB
    widgetsnbextension-3.5.1   |           py36_0         862 KB
    x264-1!152.20180806        |       h7b6447c_0         631 KB
    zeromq-4.3.1               |       he6710b0_3         496 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       233.8 MB

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  atomicwrites-1.3.0-py_0
  gettext-0.19.8.1-hc5be6a0_1002
  imageio-ffmpeg-0.3.0-py_0
  lz4-c-1.8.3-he1b5a44_1001
  pthread-stubs-0.4-h14c3975_1001
  xorg-libxau-1.0.9-h14c3975_0
  xorg-libxdmcp-1.1.3-h516909a_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  absl-py                                      0.7.1-py36_0 --> 0.8.1-py36_0
  asn1crypto              anaconda::asn1crypto-1.0.1-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::asn1crypto-1.3.0-py36_0
  astor                                        0.7.1-py36_0 --> 0.8.0-py36_0
  attrs              anaconda/linux-64::attrs-19.1.0-py36_1 --> pkgs/main/noarch::attrs-19.3.0-py_0
  c-ares                                  1.15.0-h7b6447c_1 --> 1.15.0-h7b6447c_1001
  cffi                 anaconda::cffi-1.12.3-py36h2e261b9_0 --> pkgs/main::cffi-1.13.2-py36h2e261b9_0
  cloudpickle              anaconda::cloudpickle-1.2.1-py_0 --> pkgs/main::cloudpickle-1.2.2-py_0
  cryptography       anaconda::cryptography-2.7-py36h1ba5d~ --> pkgs/main::cryptography-2.8-py36h1ba5d50_0
  cudnn                                    7.6.0-cuda10.0_0 --> 7.6.5-cuda10.0_0
  cytoolz            anaconda::cytoolz-0.10.0-py36h7b6447c~ --> pkgs/main::cytoolz-0.10.1-py36h7b6447c_0
  dask-core                  anaconda::dask-core-2.1.0-py_0 --> pkgs/main::dask-core-2.9.1-py_0
  dbus                  conda-forge::dbus-1.13.6-he372182_0 --> pkgs/main::dbus-1.13.12-h746ee38_0
  decorator          anaconda/linux-64::decorator-4.4.0-py~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::decorator-4.4.1-py_0
  expat              conda-forge::expat-2.2.5-he1b5a44_1003 --> pkgs/main::expat-2.2.6-he6710b0_0
  gast                pkgs/main/linux-64::gast-0.2.2-py36_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::gast-0.3.2-py_0
  glib               conda-forge::glib-2.58.3-h6f030ca_1002 --> pkgs/main::glib-2.63.1-h5a9c865_0
  imageio                    anaconda::imageio-2.5.0-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::imageio-2.6.1-py36_0
  importlib_metadata conda-forge::importlib_metadata-0.23-~ --> pkgs/main::importlib_metadata-1.3.0-py36_0
  ipykernel          anaconda::ipykernel-5.1.1-py36h39e3ca~ --> pkgs/main::ipykernel-5.1.3-py36h39e3cac_1
  ipython            anaconda::ipython-7.6.1-py36h39e3cac_0 --> pkgs/main::ipython-7.11.1-py36h39e3cac_0
  ipywidgets                anaconda::ipywidgets-7.5.0-py_0 --> pkgs/main::ipywidgets-7.5.1-py_0
  jedi                         anaconda::jedi-0.13.3-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::jedi-0.15.2-py36_0
  jinja2             anaconda/linux-64::jinja2-2.10.1-py36~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::jinja2-2.10.3-py_0
  joblib                       anaconda::joblib-0.14.0-py_0 --> pkgs/main::joblib-0.14.1-py_0
  jsonschema              anaconda::jsonschema-3.0.1-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::jsonschema-3.2.0-py36_0
  jupyter_client     anaconda/noarch::jupyter_client-5.3.1~ --> pkgs/main/linux-64::jupyter_client-5.3.4-py36_0
  jupyter_core       anaconda/noarch::jupyter_core-4.5.0-p~ --> pkgs/main/linux-64::jupyter_core-4.6.1-py36_0
  libprotobuf                              3.8.0-hd408876_0 --> 3.11.2-hd408876_0
  libtiff            conda-forge::libtiff-4.0.10-h57b8799_~ --> pkgs/main::libtiff-4.1.0-h2733197_0
  matplotlib         anaconda::matplotlib-3.1.0-py36h54297~ --> pkgs/main::matplotlib-3.1.1-py36h5429711_0
  mkl_fft                             1.0.12-py36ha843d7b_0 --> 1.0.15-py36ha843d7b_0
  mkl_random                           1.0.2-py36hd81dba3_0 --> 1.1.0-py36hd6b4f25_0
  more-itertools     conda-forge::more-itertools-7.2.0-py_0 --> pkgs/main::more-itertools-8.0.2-py_0
  nbconvert           anaconda/noarch::nbconvert-5.5.0-py_0 --> pkgs/main/linux-64::nbconvert-5.6.1-py36_0
  networkx                      anaconda::networkx-2.3-py_0 --> pkgs/main::networkx-2.4-py_0
  notebook                  anaconda::notebook-6.0.0-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::notebook-6.0.2-py36_0
  numpy                               1.16.4-py36h7e9f1db_0 --> 1.17.4-py36hc1035e2_0
  numpy-base                          1.16.4-py36hde5b4d6_0 --> 1.17.4-py36hde5b4d6_0
  openssl            conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1d-h516909a_0 --> pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1d-h7b6447c_3
  packaging          pkgs/main/linux-64::packaging-19.0-py~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::packaging-20.0-py_0
  parso                          anaconda::parso-0.5.0-py_0 --> pkgs/main::parso-0.5.2-py_0
  pcre                 conda-forge::pcre-8.41-hf484d3e_1003 --> pkgs/main::pcre-8.43-he6710b0_0
  pillow              anaconda::pillow-6.1.0-py36h34e0f95_0 --> pkgs/main::pillow-7.0.0-py36hb39fc2d_0
  pip                                         19.1.1-py36_0 --> 19.3.1-py36_0
  pluggy             conda-forge/noarch::pluggy-0.12.0-py_0 --> pkgs/main/linux-64::pluggy-0.13.1-py36_0
  prompt_toolkit     anaconda/linux-64::prompt_toolkit-2.0~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::prompt_toolkit-2.0.10-py_0
  protobuf                             3.8.0-py36he6710b0_0 --> 3.11.2-py36he6710b0_0
  psutil              anaconda::psutil-5.6.3-py36h7b6447c_0 --> pkgs/main::psutil-5.6.7-py36h7b6447c_0
  py                             conda-forge::py-1.8.0-py_0 --> pkgs/main::py-1.8.1-py_0
  pygments                    anaconda::pygments-2.4.2-py_0 --> pkgs/main::pygments-2.5.2-py_0
  pyopenssl               anaconda::pyopenssl-19.0.0-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::pyopenssl-19.1.0-py36_0
  pyparsing                  anaconda::pyparsing-2.4.0-py_0 --> pkgs/main::pyparsing-2.4.6-py_0
  pyqt                  anaconda::pyqt-5.9.2-py36h22d08a2_1 --> pkgs/main::pyqt-5.9.2-py36h05f1152_2
  pyrsistent         anaconda::pyrsistent-0.14.11-py36h7b6~ --> pkgs/main::pyrsistent-0.15.6-py36h7b6447c_0
  pytest                   conda-forge::pytest-5.2.2-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::pytest-5.3.2-py36_0
  python-dateutil    anaconda/linux-64::python-dateutil-2.~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::python-dateutil-2.8.1-py_0
  pytz                           anaconda::pytz-2019.1-py_0 --> pkgs/main::pytz-2019.3-py_0
  pywavelets         anaconda::pywavelets-1.0.3-py36hdd077~ --> pkgs/main::pywavelets-1.1.1-py36h7b6447c_0
  pyyaml                               5.1.1-py36h7b6447c_0 --> 5.2-py36h7b6447c_0
  pyzmq               anaconda::pyzmq-18.0.0-py36he6710b0_0 --> pkgs/main::pyzmq-18.1.0-py36he6710b0_0
  qtconsole                  anaconda::qtconsole-4.5.2-py_0 --> pkgs/main::qtconsole-4.6.0-py_1
  requests                 anaconda::requests-2.22.0-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::requests-2.22.0-py36_1
  scipy                                1.2.1-py36h7c811a0_0 --> 1.3.2-py36h7c811a0_0
  setuptools                                  41.0.1-py36_0 --> 44.0.0-py36_0
  six                                         1.12.0-py36_0 --> 1.13.0-py36_0
  sqlite                                  3.28.0-h7b6447c_0 --> 3.30.1-h7b6447c_0
  terminado                anaconda::terminado-0.8.2-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::terminado-0.8.3-py36_0
  testpath           anaconda/linux-64::testpath-0.4.2-py3~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::testpath-0.4.4-py_0
  traitlets                anaconda::traitlets-4.3.2-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::traitlets-4.3.3-py36_0
  urllib3                   anaconda::urllib3-1.24.2-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::urllib3-1.25.7-py36_0
  werkzeug                                      0.15.4-py_0 --> 0.16.0-py_0
  wheel                                       0.33.4-py36_0 --> 0.33.6-py36_0
  widgetsnbextension anaconda::widgetsnbextension-3.5.0-py~ --> pkgs/main::widgetsnbextension-3.5.1-py36_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  anaconda-client                                  anaconda --> pkgs/main
  backcall                                         anaconda --> pkgs/main
  backports                                        anaconda --> pkgs/main
  bleach                                           anaconda --> pkgs/main
  bzip2                 conda-forge::bzip2-1.0.8-h516909a_0 --> pkgs/main::bzip2-1.0.8-h7b6447c_0
  ca-certificates    conda-forge::ca-certificates-2019.11.~ --> pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2019.11.27-0
  certifi                                       conda-forge --> pkgs/main
  chardet                                          anaconda --> pkgs/main
  clyent                                           anaconda --> pkgs/main
  cycler                                           anaconda --> pkgs/main
  defusedxml                                       anaconda --> pkgs/main
  entrypoints                                      anaconda --> pkgs/main
  freetype           conda-forge::freetype-2.10.0-he983fc9~ --> pkgs/main::freetype-2.9.1-h8a8886c_1
  giflib               conda-forge::giflib-5.1.9-h516909a_0 --> pkgs/main::giflib-5.1.4-h14c3975_1
  gmp                  conda-forge::gmp-6.1.2-hf484d3e_1000 --> pkgs/main::gmp-6.1.2-h6c8ec71_1
  graphite2          conda-forge::graphite2-1.3.13-hf484d3~ --> pkgs/main::graphite2-1.3.13-h23475e2_0
  gst-plugins-base   conda-forge::gst-plugins-base-1.14.5-~ --> pkgs/main::gst-plugins-base-1.14.0-hbbd80ab_1
  gstreamer          conda-forge::gstreamer-1.14.5-h36ae1b~ --> pkgs/main::gstreamer-1.14.0-hb453b48_1
  icu                   conda-forge::icu-58.2-hf484d3e_1000 --> pkgs/main::icu-58.2-h9c2bf20_1
  idna                                             anaconda --> pkgs/main
  ipython_genutils                                 anaconda --> pkgs/main
  jasper             conda-forge::jasper-1.900.1-h07fcdf6_~ --> pkgs/main::jasper-1.900.1-hd497a04_4
  jupyter_console                                  anaconda --> pkgs/main
  kiwisolver                                       anaconda --> pkgs/main
  lame                conda-forge::lame-3.100-h14c3975_1001 --> pkgs/main::lame-3.100-h7b6447c_0
  libiconv           conda-forge::libiconv-1.15-h516909a_1~ --> pkgs/main::libiconv-1.15-h63c8f33_5
  libpng              conda-forge::libpng-1.6.37-hed695b0_0 --> pkgs/main::libpng-1.6.37-hbc83047_0
  libsodium                                        anaconda --> pkgs/main
  libwebp             conda-forge::libwebp-1.0.2-h576950b_1 --> pkgs/main::libwebp-1.0.1-h8e7db2f_0
  libxcb             conda-forge::libxcb-1.13-h14c3975_1002 --> pkgs/main::libxcb-1.13-h1bed415_1
  libxml2             conda-forge::libxml2-2.9.9-h13577e0_1 --> pkgs/main::libxml2-2.9.9-hea5a465_1
  markupsafe                                       anaconda --> pkgs/main
  mistune                                          anaconda --> pkgs/main
  mkl-service                                      anaconda --> pkgs/main
  nbformat                                         anaconda --> pkgs/main
  olefile                                          anaconda --> pkgs/main
  openh264           conda-forge::openh264-1.8.0-hdbcaa40_~ --> pkgs/main::openh264-1.8.0-hd408876_0
  pandoc                                           anaconda --> pkgs/main
  pandocfilters                                    anaconda --> pkgs/main
  pexpect                                          anaconda --> pkgs/main
  pickleshare                                      anaconda --> pkgs/main
  pixman             conda-forge::pixman-0.38.0-h516909a_1~ --> pkgs/main::pixman-0.38.0-h7b6447c_0
  prometheus_client                                anaconda --> pkgs/main
  ptyprocess                                       anaconda --> pkgs/main
  pycparser                                        anaconda --> pkgs/main
  pysocks                                          anaconda --> pkgs/main
  pytest-runner                                 conda-forge --> pkgs/main
  python-utils       conda-forge/noarch::python-utils-2.3.~ --> pkgs/main/linux-64::python-utils-2.3.0-py36_0
  qt                       conda-forge::qt-5.9.7-h52cfd70_2 --> pkgs/main::qt-5.9.7-h5867ecd_1
  qtpy                                             anaconda --> pkgs/main
  send2trash                                       anaconda --> pkgs/main
  sip                  anaconda::sip-4.19.13-py36he6710b0_0 --> pkgs/main::sip-4.19.8-py36hf484d3e_0
  toolz                                            anaconda --> pkgs/main
  tornado                                          anaconda --> pkgs/main
  tqdm                                          conda-forge --> pkgs/main
  wcwidth                                          anaconda --> pkgs/main
  webencodings                                     anaconda --> pkgs/main
  x264               conda-forge::x264-1!152.20180806-h14c~ --> pkgs/main::x264-1!152.20180806-h7b6447c_0
  zeromq                                           anaconda --> pkgs/main
  zipp                                          conda-forge --> pkgs/main
  zstd                   conda-forge::zstd-1.4.0-h3b9ef0a_0 --> pkgs/main::zstd-1.3.7-h0b5b093_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? n
```

Why is this? How can I uninstall this version of `imageio-ffmpeg` without putting my entire environment at risk??

As background, I started trying to install/uninstall this package because I'm trying to use the `moviepy` package. When I tried to import this package, I got the following error:

```
RuntimeError: imageio.ffmpeg.download() has been deprecated. Use 'pip install imageio-ffmpeg' instead.'
```

Instead of following it verbatim, I installed `imageio-ffmpeg` using `conda`,, but still received the same error. When I Googled my error, I found a suggested solution of

```
sudo pip3 install imageio==2.4.1
```

So, now I want to ensure my `conda` install doesn't supercede my planned `pip3` install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Asymmetry

In the installation part, Conda runs with an implicit `--freeze-installed` flag, making it a simple install if all the packages are already there.

In the uninstallation, Conda doesn't have an equivalent simple uninstall. Instead, it will attempt to remove the requested package, plus any of its dependencies that were not explicitly installed or required by other packages. Unfortunately, it appears to accomplish this by trying to solve for an environment that consists of only previously requested packages for the env, and this means that all packages that have superseding versions are subject to being updated.

Your particular case appears to be exacerbated by the fact that you have installed from different channels (e.g., **conda-forge**), but never explicitly defined those channel priorities in your Conda configuration (globally or in the env). So, most of the changes involve switching back to the **defaults** channel version of packages.

### Alternatives

If you're confident that nothing else has changed, then you could use the `--force-remove` flag.

Another option, if this was the latest thing you've installed, is to try a revision roll-back, but this may also result in drastic changes. That is, check your revision history:

```
conda list --revisions
```

And then attempt installing the penultimate one. I'd definitely dry-run it first:

```
conda install --revision <your_rev> --dry-run
```

### Pip

Don't use Pip unless you absolutely must, and definitely not in your **base** env. Generally, using Pip with Conda leads to instability (see [Using Pip in a Conda Environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env)).  Also, if you do have to use it, don't use `sudo` or `pip3`. Instead, activate the env and use simply `pip install`.

### General (Opinionated) Recommendation

Personally, I've found the most stable way to work with Conda is to *treat all envs as immutable*. That is, avoid using `conda (install|update|remove|uninstall)` commands. The only exception to this is when first specifying a new project.

Instead of *ad hoc* installation and removal of packages, write a YAML file and use that to create a new env (`conda env create -f my_env.yml`) whenever you wish to edit your environment. If you need to add a new package to the env, edit the YAML and recreate the env from scratch.