# Does the `conda uninstall` and `pip uninstall` also removing dependencies but only ones that are not used by other packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, conda

Does the `conda uninstall` and `pip uninstall` also removing dependencies for package that I am specifying in uninstall command but only ones that are not dependencies for any other currently installed packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at docs, the answer is easy to come by.

[Conda remove](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/remove.html) man page plainly says:

> This command will also remove any package that depends on any of the
>   specified packages as well---unless a replacement can be found without
>   that dependency. If you wish to skip this dependency checking and
>   remove just the requested packages, add the '--force' option. Note
>   however that this may result in a broken environment, so use this with
>   caution.

[pip uninstall](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_uninstall/) on the other hand requires a `-r` option to delete package requirements.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for Conda remove isn't clear. It doesn't explicitly address the situation of whether shared dependencies are removed and the statement "--unless a replacement can be found without that dependency" only further confuses things.

This [answer from Merv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59814288/3586981), if correct, indicates shared dependencies are not removed:

> In the uninstallation, Conda...will attempt to remove the requested package, plus any of its dependencies that were not explicitly installed or required by other packages.